# Using EnOcean PI 868 with raspberry PI4

Tags: serial, pi-4, radio

first of all: I'm new to raspberry

I.ve just bought a raspberry PI 4 together with an EnOcean PI 868 module to set up a house automation system. To make it run I've tried the steps described on the [element14 site](https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-55295/l/element14-how-to-use-enocean-pi-with-raspberry-pi) and also used `sudo stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 57600` + `hexdump -C < /dev/ttyAMA0` to see at least a single byte received .. with no success.

Of course I've read about the nessessary setup for PI3 like

- enabling serial
- disabling serial console
- adding `dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt` to /boot/config.txt

and did so. The only differnece I've seen is in /boot/cmdline.txt: tototrials say 'find a line startiing with `wc_otg.lpm_enable=0` and remove `console=serial0,115200` but I don't have such al line.

**Edit**

some more things I've found or tried so far:

- the EnOcean PI 868 uses serial UART gpio 14 &15 and web research always brings me to these points, which are in genereal related to PI 3B but seem to be true for  PI4 too:
- /dev/ttyAMA0 is by default used for blutooth, /dev/ttyS0 as 'miniuart' for serial
- you can switch devices by adding `dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt` to /boot/config.txt
- /dev/ttyAMA0 is also used for serial if you disable blutooth completely with `dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt` to /boot/config.txt
- the simplest way to see if anything is received is by calling `stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 (or ttyS0) 57600 (115200 in other posts)` + `hexdump -C < /dev/ttyXXX`

Comment: Hi @Ingo Leonhardt, Welcome.  Ah, let me see. So my dear Rpi newbie, you have a new 2019 Rpi4 and you are following a 2012, ie, 6 years old tutorial for Rpi2? My suggestion is the following: If you have found two cockroaches in any very outdated tutorial, I mean more than 2 years old, remember what the wise guy Warren Buffett says: https://www.cnbc.com/2017/08/30/warren-buffett-on-wells-fargo-theres-never-just-one-cockroach-in-the-kitchen.html.

Comment: @tlfong01 thanks for reading my question but unfortunaltely your comment isn't very helpful. In the comments to he tutorial are several comments mentioning concering serial on P3B and from everyting I have found so far this should all york with PI4 as well.

Comment: I am sorry that I have not been helpful. If beside the problems you mentioned, the seemingly old tutorial can still be good, I need to look at it again, and make an apology to your and Element14.  Actually I have been a huge fan of Element14 Hongkong since the Rpi1 days, and so far I have no complaints, except I always tell them that I am just a poor hobbyist doing Micky Mouse projects, therefore cannot afford their a bit expensive industrial grade products. Happy UART programming and cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for PI4, if you want to read from EnOcean PI 868 via `/dev/ttyS0` you have to enable `raw` mode too:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 57600 raw
hexdump -C < /dev/ttyS0
```

Shows hex dumps of EnOcean telegrams on stdout

That's a good stating point to write my own implementation

Answer (score 0):

Have you had any success with integrating the Enocean components?

One of the few sources of useful information that I have found is the [FHEM instructions](https://wiki.fhem.de/wiki/EnOcean_Starter_Guide#Definition_.2F_Anlernvorgang_.28Teach-In.29). I would like to add a range of Eltako components to Domoticz or Homeassistant. Adding a relay, e.g. Eltako fsr61-230V is not an easy, which is unfortunate, especially since there a few manufacturers in addition to Eltako, which provide the full-range of CE certified components that are not based on some propriety software or protocol.

Comment: This does not seem to solve the problem: it seems to be a discussion

Comment: Yes I'm now able to read and interpret enocean telegrams from switches (the only enocean devices I'm using at the moment). I have built my house automation from scratch (lights and roller shutters only). After I was finally able to read from /dev/ttyS0 the rest was not a problem, the official EnOcean documents are quite good.